# Administrative password not accepted

Tags: password, root

My password works when I log on, and it works when I'm in Terminal and I am accessing Root.

The problem is when I try to install a Lexmark S405 printer driver in Terminal I'm asked for the "Administrative password" and it will not accept it--says it's wrong. (I double click the installer and choose "Run in Terminal")

I even changed the password with the same results.

I've tried my user name as well with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The "Administrative password" that it's asking for is the `root` password, which is not set by default. You have two solutions:

1. You can set the `root` password, and then use that password to install your driver. However, it is best practice to *not* set a `root` password unless you really need to, because that opens up lots of other doors that may lead to accidental deletion of stuff and all that, so you should go with solution number 2.
2. Open a terminal by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and do `sudo /path/to/driver`. So, let's say you downloaded the driver in your Downloads folder, you would do `sudo ~/Downloads/filename`. The password that it will ask for is your username's password.

On a side note though, what is the extension of this printer driver? Because I wanted to see for myself, so I visited the [Lexmark Support & Downloads](http://support.lexmark.com/index?productCode=LEXMARK_INTERPRET_S405&page=product&locale=EN&userlocale=EN#2) page for that printer, chose OS = Linux, version = Ubuntu 12.04, and all the files are in .deb format, so these shouldn't ask you to "Run in terminal" when you double click them.